# gRPC/protobuf generated Python files use incorrect import statements

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-python, protobuf-python

I have a grpc repo included in a python project repo as a submodule at `src/grpc/protobuf` with the following example structure:

```
protobuf/
  |
  |-data_structs/
  |   |-example_structA.proto
  |   |-example_structB.proto
  |   
  |-messages/
  |   |-example_messageA.proto
  |   |-example_messageB.proto
  |
  |-services/
      |-example_service.proto
```

With simplified example implementations:

```
//example_structA.proto

syntax = "proto3"

message example_structA {
    int id = 1;
}
```

```
//example_structB.proto

syntax = "proto3"

import "data_structs/example_structA.proto";

message example_structB {
     int id = 1;
     repeated example_structA items = 2;
}
```

```
//example_messageA.proto

syntax = "proto3"

import "data_structs/example_structB.proto"

message example_messageA {
    string info = 1;
    example_structB data = 2;
}
```

```
//example_messageB.proto

syntax = "proto3"

message example_messageB {
    string status = 1;
}
```

```
//example_service.proto

syntax = "proto3"

import "messages/example_messageA.proto";
import "messages/example_messageB.proto";

service example_service {
    rpc SendMessage (example_messageA) returns (example_messageB) {}
}
```

I am generating the python code with the following command, run from the python projects root dir:

```
find src/grpc/protobuf -name "*.proto" | xargs python -m grpc_tools.protoc =I=./src/grpc/protobuf --python_out=./src/grpc/generated --grpc_python_out=./src/grpc/generated
```

This correctly generates .py files in the src/grpc/generated directory, and places them into subdirectories that mimic the proto repo structure. e.g. the files for `example_structB` are located at `src/grpc/generated/data_structs/example_structB_pb2.py` and `src/grpc/generated/data_structs/example_structB_pb2_grpc.py` messages are in the `src/grpc/generated/messages` directory, etc.

These generated files have faulty imports generated though.

`example_structB_pb2.py` has `from data_structs import example_structA_pb2` This should be `from . import example_structA_pb2` or simply `import example_structA_pb2`

`example_messageA_pb2.py` has `from data_structs import example_structB_pb2` This should be `from ..data_structs import example_structB_pb2`

So on and so forth. Services importing messages should be `from ..messages import` instead of just `from messages import`

I have not had any issues using this directory/proto structure and generation in java or c++. Is there any way to resolve this for python generated code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a bug it is working as intended, [pyi_generator.cc:168](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/5e7b709564403f1fe22476f7efa1eeff61e995cb/src/google/protobuf/compiler/python/pyi_generator.cc#L168) add's the path from the `--python_out` as the argument to the `from` and it does not checking if it is accesible by the root (if you make the entry point the same as the out path with `python_out=./`, it should work without the `export`)
and it's also disallowed the use of `..` in a path ([importer.cc:341](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/5e7b709564403f1fe22476f7efa1eeff61e995cb/src/google/protobuf/compiler/importer.cc#L341)) so your solution is the valid one but i would have preferred to add the path from inside python, like in here:

```
# this line is somewhere before the import of the proto-stuff
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'src', 'grpc', 'generated'))
```

Basic example (edit 1)

If you have a tree like this, with the source folder containing an exact sub-tree as if it is under `./`, the topest folder will be in the entry dir, this means that it will compile with the correct import just because its the same structure.

```
root
│  <your main>.py
│  proto_compile.py
└─ proto_src
   └─ proto_py
        │  base.proto
        └─ structs
            ├─ message
            │    type_blob.proto
            │    type_text.proto
            └─ utils
                 blob.proto
```

In python, the imports are "in `sys.path`" finds, the entry point is added to that list at the beginning of the execution and the `.` is independent from that, it is relative to that file even if that file is not in a known dir. Then if you have a dir that cant follow a "branching from root" import style you just add that path to the `sys.path` (but this could lead to a circular import problem if you add paths from inside the project).

These are the files to test:

```
# proto_compile.py

import subprocess
import os

def get_proto_files(path):
    proto_files = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for name in files:
            if name.rsplit('.')[-1] == 'proto':
                proto_files.append(
                    # path is relative !
                    os.path.join(root, name)
                )
    return proto_files

def run_protoc(exe_path, src, dst):
    popen = subprocess.Popen(
        [
            exe_path,
            f'--proto_path={src}',
            f'--python_out={dst}'
        ] + get_proto_files(src),
        # could olso use os.getcwd()
        cwd=os.path.dirname(__file__),
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
    )
    while popen.returncode is None:
        stdout, stderr = popen.communicate()
        if stdout is not None:
            print(stdout.decode())
        if stderr is not None:
            print(stderr.decode())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_protoc(
        './protobuff/bin/protoc.exe',
        './proto_src',
        './'
    )
```

```
// base.proto

syntax = "proto3";

import "proto_py/structs/message/type_blob.proto";
import "proto_py/structs/message/type_text.proto";

message user_message {
    int32 id = 1;
    oneof content {
        content_text  text  = 2;
        content_image image = 3;
    }
}
```

```
// type_text.proto

syntax = "proto3";

message content_text {
    int32 id = 1;
}
```

```
// type_blob.proto

syntax = "proto3";

import "proto_py/structs/utils/blob.proto";

message content_image {
    int32 id = 1;
    blob_check check = 2;
}
```

```
// blob.proto

syntax = "proto3";

message blob_check {
    string sha256 = 1;
}
```

Comment: I'm not following what you mean by making entry point the same as python_out. Can you give the example protoc call?

Comment: The example uses python to compile it but that is just because im using windows

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by exporting src/grpc/generated to my PYTHONPATH

`export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/project/root/src/grpc/generated`